# Why doesn't Boba Fett just point out where the Falcon is?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Boba Fett waits for the Falcon to detach from the star destroyer so he can follow them. Clearly he has some idea what Han has probably done to hide. Why would he not simply point out the possibility before they leave and thereby claim the bounty? It seems vastly safer and more likely to succeed than chasing them down.

Comment: Do you have anything to show that he "probably knew what Han had probably done to hide"? This question appears to be entirely based in speculation..

Comment: Because if he's wrong, he'll look like an idiot

Comment: He sat in the debris field Han was using to hide, quietly, while everyone else flew off. He clearly suspected he would find something.

Comment: @Gnemlock - Not sure how it stands in the realms of Canon but Boba Fett's entry in Star Wars.com says he had realised and was waiting.

Answer (score 22):

There's nothing *in the movie* which suggests Boba Fett knew where the Millenium Falcon was. Instead, he had a hunch it had never left and was hiding *somewhere*. He knew there was no cloaking device, Han had just outsmarted the Imperials. So, he reasoned, if he hides out until the Imperial fleet departs, Han will reveal himself.

---

But let's say he did know, I have no idea what's canon these days. Why wouldn't he tell the Imperials immediately? Let's do some speculating.

Boba Fett's no dummy, he knows about Vader's tendency to "alter the deal". He wants to make sure he's put in a good effort to find Han and nobody can have any doubt that it was Boba Fett who tracked and found Han, and it was Boba Fett who should be paid. If he'd said "he's attached to your ship" the Imperials might not have been inclined to pay him, or cut his fee. The old joke about the plumber who takes 1 minute to fix your furnace and charges you $100 for their expertise in knowing where to look might not go over so well with Vader.

He doesn't want to make the Imperials, his employers, look bad. Blurting out "he's just attached to your ship somewhere" makes them look like idiots. Making Vader look like an idiot is a great way to get Force Choked.

Boba Fett has a reputation to keep up as one of the best bounty hunters and trackers in the galaxy. You don't get that reputation by revealing your tricks in front of all your competitors and client. "I tracked him all the way to the Bespin system using my amazing tracking skills!" sounds a lot better than "I figured he'd just be hiding until you left."

---

Don't forget, Boba Fett is working *two* bounties for the same prize. There's the Imperial bounty, and there's Jabba's bounty on Han. If he hands the Falcon over the Imperials, he might get the Imperial bounty, but he'll lose Jabba's bounty. Worse, when Jabba finds out Boba Fett handed "his" prize to the Imperials, Boba Fett might find a bounty on *his* head.

So Boba Fett waits until he's found the Falcon and the Imperial fleet is well on its wild goose chase. Then he makes a phone call to Vader, "I've found the Falcon. I'll tell you where it's going, but on one condition: I keep Han."

---

Finally, maybe Boba Fett did tell the Imperials.

Vader didn't really want the Falcon, he wanted Luke. The Falcon (more importantly, its occupants) are just bait. Fett would realize the Falcon's hyperdrive was crippled and informed Vader. Vader could have realized the Falcon would have to land for repairs. Rather than chasing "the fastest hunk of junk in the galaxy" around some more, it would be a trivial matter to capture them while they're undergoing repairs at some backwater.

So rather than racing in with the whole fleet, Vader might have told Fett to follow the Falcon until it landed. Then Vader could easily and quietly bottle them up and wait for Luke to show up.

Comment: So the answer as far as we know from canon: Fett only noticed the Falcon as it departed, and therefore pursued it- that's certainly what I've always taken away from it.

Comment: Well, I (clearly) disagree that there's nothing in the movie to suggest Boba knew where the Falcon was. He obviously suspected, or he wouldn't have hid out in the garbage field. But your comment about Vader wanting to capture them off the ship is definitely worthwhile. Upvoted.

Comment: Great answer, although I can imagine there is one more similar factor: We see a whole bunch of bounty hunters being instructed by Darth Vader. If it's about being sure that "nobody can have any doubt that it was Boba Fett who tracked and found Han, and it was Boba Fett who should be paid", maybe the other bounty hunters are even more of a concern than the Imperials.

Comment: Well, just saying "he's on the hull" before anyone else can would seem to take care of that possibility...

Answer (score 8):

Fett was employed to find them and being them back alive for a "substantial reward."

His decision outmaneuvered and outsmarted a group of his bounty hunter competitors and a large section of the Imperial Navy led by Darth Vader.

Had he simply called the Empire and said, "He's there!" he may not have gained the reward and he certainly would not have gained as much recognition.

He took a greater risk but you know what they say about risk and reward.